# Derivation of the irreducible representations of SO(3)

Tags: group-representations, lie-algebra, representation-theory

Is there a way to derive the representations of $SO(3)$ *without* the usual method with the ladder operators which also gives the ones of $SU(2)$?

The usual way to do these calculations is to start from the commutation relations of the Lie algebra associated with $SU(2)$ (or that of $SO(3)$, which is the same given that $\mathfrak{so}(3) \approx \mathfrak{su}(2)$ as far as I understand) and from there to go throught the ladder-operators-thing to obtain *all* of the representations of $SU(2)$. Is there another way to derive the representations of $SO(3)$ which is *specific* of $SO(3)$ and not also applicable to $SU(2)$?

Comment: It is inefficient to derive the reps of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ alone. It is a general principle that, given a Lie group, all its linear reps are induced by linear reps of its universal cover. Therefore, it always suffices to look at the universal cover, which in the case of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. Why would you want to make your life harder by not looking at that?

Comment: @ACuriousMind because I wanted to understand what properties of $SO(3)$ restrict its representations to be integer-spin ones

Comment: The relevant property is that $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ *double covers* $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, and if you look which reps project down nicely along the covering map, you find they are precisely the integer spin ones.

Comment: @ACuriousMind well I'm sure that that is extremely insightful... for who understands what it means :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful.  It may be the case that $\mathfrak{su}(2)=\mathfrak{so}(3)$, but it is *not* the case that $SU(2)=SO(3)$.  $SU(2)=\mathrm{Spin}(3)$ and $\rho :SU(2)\rightarrow SO(3)$ is the two-sheeted universal cover of $SO(3)$.  It thus turns out that only the integer spin representations of $SU(2)$ factor through $\rho$ to give well-defined representations of $SO(3)$.

Concretely, the spherical harmonics $Y_{\ell m}(\theta ,\phi )$ span an irreducible representation of $SO(3)$ in $L^2(S^2)$.  This representation has spin $\ell$ (dimension $2\ell +1$), and this yields all the finite-dimensional irreducible complex representations of $SO(3)$.  Note that $\ell$ must be an integer in this context (and so it does not give you all the irreducible representations of $SU(2)$).

Comment: Ok, but that is the "usual" way isn't it? Being that the representations of $SU(2)$ are those of $SO(3)$ plus more, the method with ladder operators $J_\pm$ starting from the commutation relations of the Lie algebra gives all the (finite-dimensional, irreducible) representations of $SU(2)$ and hence between those the ones of $SO(3)$. What I am asking is if there is some method to *specifically* derive the irreps of $SO(3)$, *without* also getting those of $SU(2)$. Which means probably without using the associated Lie algebra, but I am not sure about this

Comment: The spherical harmonics give you all the irreducible representations of $SO(3)$, but it does not give you all those of $SU(2)$.  You'll note this does not make any direct reference to the Lie algebra of $SO(3)$

Comment: You're absolutely right, I realized that just after I added the last comment. This makes me wonder: what, from the group theory point of view, leads to the restriction of the values of the orbital angular momentum? I guess it comes from the fact that $L_i = \varepsilon_{ijk} x_j p_k$, but how is this expressed in the language of group theory?

Comment: Suppose that the representation has spin $n/2$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.  Then, in particular, this representation will contain an element $v$ such that $S_zv=\frac{n}{2}v$.  This is at the level of the Lie algebra.  At the level of the Lie group, $R_z(\theta )=\exp (-i\theta S_z)$ is a rotation about the $z$-axis by an angle $\theta$.  Hence, $R_z(\theta )v=\exp (-i\theta \frac{n}{2})$.  For $\theta =2\pi$, we had better have that $R_z(2\pi )=R_z(0)$; however, using the formula above, $R_z(2\pi )=\exp (-i\pi)=-1$.  Thus, this does not give us a representation of $SO(3)$ for half-integer spin.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is to exclude half-integer angular momentum representations because they require 720° of rotation to get the state back to itself? We accept this property for spin angular momentum though, why should we a priori consider it unacceptable for the orbital one? However I was thinking of a reason coming from the mathematical properties of the definition of the orbital angular momentum that further restrict its representations. For example, could this be related to $L_i$ be an antisymmetric tensor?

Comment: This is exactly what I am suggesting.

This has nothing to do with spin vs. orbital.  If somebody has told you that spin in $SO(3)$ can change a sign after a rotation by $2\pi$, they were wrong.  This can only happen for spin with $SU(2)$.  The point is is that, in quantum mechanics, we don't really care about representations, but rather *projective* representations (basically representations up to phase).  It turns out that projective representations of $SO(3)$ are in canonical one-to-one correspondence with actual representations of $SU(2)$.

Comment: Also, it cannot be related to $L_i$ at all.  $L_i$ is an element of the Lie algebra, and we know that $\mathfrak{su}(2)=\mathfrak{so}(3)$.

Comment: Thanks for your effort to explain! Just one more thing about the minus one: you used the phase acquired by a state rotating 360° in an half-integer spin rep to rule out these as reps of $SO(3)$. What I don't get in that argument is why should we a priori consider this property as unacceptable for $SO(3)$ while acceptable for $SU(2)$ (I understand that the phase factor poses no physical contradiction because what matters is the squared modulus, I'm just arguing on the a priori ruling it out for $SO(3)$)

Comment: The same principle applies to both $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$.  All this essentially comes down to the trivial fact that, if $x=y$, then we must have that $f(x)=f(y)$.  In $SO(3)$, the identity element and the element that rotates by $\pi$ *are the same element*.  Hence, they must do the same thing in a representation.  Obviously, this principle is still true for $SU(2)$; however, in this case, we have *distinct* $g,h\in SU(2)$ such that $\rho (g)=\rho (h)=1\in SO(3)$ ($\rho :SU(2)\rightarrow SO(3)$ is the map I mentioned in my answer).