# Connection between half and whole integer eigenvalues for orbital angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, quantum-spin, commutator

I have been trying to follow this derivation from Sakurai and Shankar, pulling from both. I would like to see how the following derivation can be extended to orbital angular momentum, and thus find that $\ell$ is an integer. The details are omitted but the core of the proof is here.

Consider the following

$$
  \begin{align*}
    [\hat{J}^2,\hat{J}_z] &= 0 \\
    [\hat{J}_z,\hat{J}_\pm] &= \pm\hbar\hat{J}_\pm \\
    \hat{J}_\pm &\equiv \hat{J}_x \pm \mathrm{i}\hat{J}_y.
  \end{align*}
$$

Now let
$$
  \begin{align*}
    \hat{J}^2 \lvert \alpha, \beta \rangle 
    &= \alpha \lvert \alpha, \beta \rangle \\
    %
    \hat{J}_z \lvert \alpha, \beta \rangle 
    &= \beta \lvert \alpha, \beta \rangle
  \end{align*}
$$

From the above we can see that
$$
  \hat{J}_z \hat{J}_\pm \lvert \alpha, \beta \rangle 
  = (\beta \pm \hbar) \hat{J}_\pm \lvert \alpha, \beta \rangle
$$

and
$$
  \hat{J}^2 \hat{J}_\pm \lvert \alpha, \beta \rangle 
  = \hat{J}_\pm \hat{J}^2 \lvert \alpha, \beta \rangle
  = \alpha \hat{J}_\pm \lvert \alpha, \beta \rangle
$$

From this we see that
$$
  \hat{J}_\pm \lvert \alpha, \beta \rangle 
  \propto \lvert \alpha, (\beta + \hbar) \rangle \\
  %
  \implies \hat{J}_\pm \lvert \alpha, \beta \rangle 
  = C(\alpha,\beta) \lvert \alpha, (\beta + \hbar) \rangle.
$$

Now we see that there is an upper limit on $\beta$
$$
  \langle \alpha \beta \rvert \hat{J}^2 - \hat{J}_z^2 \lvert \alpha \beta \rangle
  = \langle \alpha \beta \rvert \hat{J}_x^2 + \hat{J}_y^2 \lvert \alpha \beta \rangle \\
  \implies \alpha \geq \beta^2
$$

So
$$
  \hat{J}_- \hat{J}_+ \lvert \alpha, \beta_{max} \rangle 
  = (\hat{J}^2 - \hat{J}_z^2 - \hbar\hat{J}_z) \lvert \alpha, \beta_{max} \rangle 
  = 0 \\
  \implies \alpha = \beta_{max}(\beta_{max} +\hbar).
$$

Similarly
$$
  \alpha = \beta_{min}(\beta_{min} +\hbar)
$$

From this we can show
$$
  \beta_{min} = -\beta_{max}.
$$

So
$$
  \beta_{max} = \frac{\hbar n}{2} \\
  \implies \frac{\beta_{max}}{\hbar} = \frac{n}{2} = j.
$$

Thus the eigenvalues are
$$
 \alpha = \hbar^2 j(j + 1).
$$

Now we define
$$
  \beta \equiv m \hbar
$$

and we have the eigen kets
$$
  \lvert j, m \rangle
$$

where $j$ increments in half integer steps.

**Question:** So the only added restriction to the derivation of the integer values of the orbital angular momentum quantum number $\ell$ is
$$
  \vec{L} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p}.
$$
How does this added restriction require that the orbital angular momentum quantum number $\ell$ be an integer and more importantly how can I show this using the proof above?

Comment: related (though maybe on a more abstract level): http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/145789/58382. Also related is http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/159409/58382, which probably contains the answer to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Half integer eigenvalues of orbital angular momentum](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153369/)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you want, but it's something. The definition
$$ \vec{L}=\vec{r}\times\vec{p} $$
combined with $\vec{p}=-i\hbar\vec{\nabla}$ implies that the the $z$ projection may be written as
$$ L_{z} = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}.$$
Where $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle. Since $L_{z}|\ell m\rangle = m\hbar |\ell m\rangle$, the $\phi$ dependence of the wave function can be written as $e^{im\phi}$. In order for the wave function to be single-valued, we require
$$ e^{im\phi} = e^{im(\phi+2\pi)}$$
and so $m$ must be an integer, and thus so must $\ell$.

Comment: This is the reason. A Details worth adding might be that this shows up in the coordinate space representation, so in real space. Which is the part differentiating it from spin with half integers.